# Connection refused error in python scrapy with seleniumrc

Tags: python, ajax, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new in scrapy,python. for dynamic loading I have used ajax call for crawl spider. I am not able to crawl the page.The code I written is:

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from demo.items import demo
from selenium import webdriver

class demoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "demodallurls"
    allowed_domains = ["demo.com/businessfinder/"]

    start_urls = ['http://www.demo.com/businessfinder/company/All/All/A/']
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        hxs = Selector(response)
        item = demoItem
        finalurls = []

        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="ver_11 viewLink"]/a')
            print "-------------next------------",next


            try:
                next.click()
                item['page'] = response.url

                urls = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//h3[@class="fleft"]/a')
                print "===============urls============",urls

                for url in urls:
                    url = url.get_attribute("href")
                    print "...................url.......................",url
                    finalurls.append(url)
                    item['urls'] = finalurls

            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()
        return item
```

my Items.py for this is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item,Field

class demoItem(scrapy.Item):
    page = Field()
    urls = Field()
    pass
```

when I am trying to crawl it I got an error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

Comment: On which line does it fail? (the traceback is not complete)

Comment: Are you using proxies?

Comment: @alecxe When I am trying to crawl it at that time it is showing error.

Comment: @VincentBeltman nope not really how I can use proxy with python-scrapy

Comment: Try debugging this by putting a print on every line. This way you can see what line is causing the problem and will help us help you.

Comment: So you're trying to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub` and the error is `Connection refused`. Sounds like there is nothing listening at that host/port.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yp kind of.